# sumo-launchd is still missing from inet-3.0.0 to later release for VANETs simulation

Tags: networking, omnet++, inet, veins

currently I am trying to simulate the existing MANET routing protocols (AODV, OLSR, GPSR, etc.)for VANET using OMNeT++-4.6, INET-3.2.3, and SUMO-0.25.0 for the simulation. But I have noticed that sumo-launchd.py such as Traci Mobility is missing from INET-3.0.0 to later releases.

Is there any alternative way of coupling the sumo with the inet framework or I need to use Veins to solve this problem? If I need to use veins framework, then which thing I have to consider for the simulation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing from the [SUMO Wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Topics/V2X) V2X environments currently in active development are

- [Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/)
- [VSimRTI](http://www.dcaiti.tu-berlin.de/research/simulation/)
- iCS

Only the first two support Omnet++ and only the first and the third are free and open source (and only the first has sumo-launchd.py). There may be other tools out there and since the tools are open you can always develop your own but probably Veins is the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes, i can use veins for this purpose but existing Manet routing protocols for V2X environments may need to consider several parameters and compatibility issues too. I want to use SUMO, INET, and Veins framework for the simulation and performance evaluation. Can i use sumo-launchd.py as a coupling of sumo and inet?

Comment: I am not so familiar with INET but there is definitely more to a coupling than just sumo-launchd.py which is basically only a wrapper script. So you will need all of Veins here.

Comment: You can use models from both Veins and INET in the same simulation

Comment: @christoph-sommer, can i use latest Veins and INET for VANET simulation using existing AODV, GPSR etc. routing protocol? Thanks.

Comment: I do not know which models are implemented in the INET version that Veins is compatible with. You can easily check by looking into the source code though

Comment: @ChristophSommer, i will consider by looking through source code of INET or INETMANET framework alongside with Veins and SUMO compatibility issues too. Thanks for the valuable feedback.